# How fix Error: This method has been removed in JSZip 3.0, please check the upgrade guide

Tags: shapefile, javascript, shp-write

I want to use [`shp-write`](https://github.com/mapbox/shp-write) for creating `shp` from geojson with pure javascript. I use it as follow:

```
var options = {
    folder: 'myshapes',
    types: {
        point: 'mypoints',
        polygon: 'mypolygons',
        line: 'mylines'
    }
}
// a GeoJSON bridge for features
shpwrite.download({
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [
        {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [103.0078125,47.39834920035926],
            [53.61328124999999,47.39834920035926],
            [94.921875,28.613459424004414],
            [103.0078125,47.39834920035926]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
    ]
}, options);
```

but this occur an error as follow:
[image]

Where is problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: what does the upgrade guide say?

Comment: @iant its Deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by hand.
Replace this:

**replace this:**

```
var generateOptions = { compression:'STORE' };

if (!process.browser) {
  generateOptions.type = 'nodebuffer';
}

return zip.generate(generateOptions);
```

**with this:**

```
var generateOptions = { compression:'STORE', type:'base64' };

if (!process.browser) {
  generateOptions.type = 'nodebuffer';
}

return zip.generateAsync(generateOptions);
```

**and this:**

```
module.exports = function(gj, options) {
  var content = zip(gj, options);
  location.href = 'data:application/zip;base64,' + content;
};
```

**with this:**

```
module.exports = function(gj, options) {
  zip(gj, options).then(function(content) {
    location.href = 'data:application/zip;base64,' + content;
  });
};
```